# Can I embed Liberation fonts in a piece of non-free software?

Tags: licensing

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts :

> As a further exception, any distribution of the object code of the Software in a physical product must provide the right to access and modify the source code for the Software and to reinstall that modified version of the Software in object code form on the same physical product on which it was received.

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly... Does this mean that if I embed such a font in my software and use it to display GUI messages, then I must open the source of this software or else I'll run afoul of the licence of this font?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  That's exactly what it means.

However, please don't link to a Wikipedia article on the fonts - link to a copy of the actual license! Searching for that, I found:

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/liberation-serif

which says that Liberation Fonts 2.0 onward are licensed under the [SIL Open Font License 1.1](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL_web) which doesn't seem to have anything about needing to open-source stuff.